# I want the screen to be white until my Tamper Monkey script loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the website to load only after this script has finished making changes.

```
document.getElementById('nav-robux-amount').innerHTML = '70k'; //Changes Robux (the bar on top)
```

Comment: Then execute the script before load of the website?

Comment: The script finishes making changes approximately 3 seconds after the page loads. If the page could just stay white for three seconds then that would work as well. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Why not try adding a timeout of 3 seconds for the load of the page? I am just giving suggestions because I am not aware of any of your code apart from the one you  posted.

Comment: How do I add a timeout for 3 seconds for the page to load xD I'm fairly new to javascript.

Comment: You can simply google it :) or you can refer this link [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)